# Is it possible ot extract the Checked state from a CheckboxField within a DetailsView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

Originally I had a TemplateField with a CheckBox in it but I couldn't set the checkbox Value using

```
Checked='<%# (bool)Bind("FieldName")  %>
```

or

```
Checked='<%# (bool)Eval("FieldName")  %>
```

It kept throwing an invalid cast exception. The field in the database is a bit field set to 1 or 0.

I tried switching to a checkbox field but because my update code is in the codebehind instead of using the updatecommand parameters in a datasource I can't seem to retrieve the value from the CheckBoxField to pass to my business logic.

Can any one point me on how to retrieve the value from the CheckBoxfield in a detailsview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't cast from int to bool.  Try `Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("FieldName"))`  Not sure if you can use `Eval` like that though, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to use `ToString()` on the value from the database, since the HTML is looking for True or False, not 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use

```
CheckBox ckBox = ucDetailView.FindControl("CheckBoxID") as CheckBox
if(ckBox != null){
   ckBox.Checked = (bool)datasource["FieldName"].ToString()
   //.. or some better casting code with more null checks
}
```

Then set it from there in code behind. Solution seemed to work [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1099687.aspx/1)

Comment: I had something like this originally but I was utilizing a checboxfield as an alternate. However because the suggestion that I accepted above worked I can continue to use this method that you mentioned.